# The following series is an irrational number

Tags: calculus

$(*)$ Let $\{ x_n \}$ be a sequence where $x_n$ is either $1$ or $-1$. Then

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ x_n}{n!} \; \; \; \text{is irrational}$$

This problem arise when I was trying to prove that $e$ is irrational. If the result above is true, then we can put $x_n = (-1)^n $ and hence

$$ \frac{1}{e} = \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \; \; \; \text{is irrational} $$

which would imply that $e$ is irrational.

So, my question is: Is $(*)$ true?

Comment: Why are you going about it in this way? The "standard" fairly elementary proof of $e$'s irrationality simply uses the usual Taylor series (with $x_n = 1$). Why do you need to invoke an alternating series?

Comment: @idm: the OP asks $x_n \in \{-1,1\}$

Comment: @BalarkaSen: thanks, voted to close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" proof of the irrationality of $e$ goes like this:

$e = 1 + 1 + \frac{1}{2!} + ... + \frac{1}{r!} + ...$

Assume to the contrary that $e$ is rational, i.e. that $e = \frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers. Clearly, $q > 1$

Now multiply both sides by $q!$:

$p!(q-1)! = q! + \frac{q!}{1!} + ...\frac{q!}{q!} + \frac{q!}{(q+1)!} + ...$

The LHS is clearly an integer (call it $M$).

The first $q+1$ terms on the RHS, i.e. up to and including $\frac{q!}{q!}$ sum up to an integer. Call this partial sum $N$.

Call the remaining partial sum $S$.

By rearrangement, $S = M - N$. Hence $S$ is a positive integer.

Also $S = \frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)(q+2)} + ...$

which can quite easily be shown to be strictly less than the geometric series:

$G = \frac{1}{q+1} + \frac{1}{(q+1)^2} + ...$

which sums to $\frac{1}{q} < 1$.

Therefore $0 < S < 1$.

Hence there is a positive integer strictly between $0$ and $1$, which is impossible, and we've arrived at a contradiction.

Hence our original assumption was false and $e$ is irrational.