# Deduce that $e$ is irrational from the following inequality....

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Deduce that $e$ is irrational from the following inequality....

$0 < e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}<\frac{1}{n!n}$ where $n\geq1$

---

Fairly straightforward to show that $0 < e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}$.Basically, I show that $e-\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$

From this, we can consider that

$\sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\dots$

Clearly, $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}<\frac{1}{n!}$. How do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "tail" $\sum_{n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ that you wrote down  is less than
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)!(n+1)^2}+\cdots.$$
The above is a geometric progression with first term $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ and common ratio $\frac{1}{n+1}$. So it has sum
$$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}},$$
which simplifies to the desired expression.

You did not ask about the rest, but as a hint suppose that $e=\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are positive integers. Multiply $e$ by $q!$ to derive a contradiction. Note that $q!\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{q!}\right)$ is an integer.

Comment: The funny thing is that I posted pretty much the same thing just yesterday as an answer to another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042102/the-following-series-is-an-irrational-number/1042125#1042125

Comment: I imagine the question has been asked a bunch of times, I have asked it of students several times. It is marginally easier to show that $e^{-1}$ is irrational, the absolute value of the tail is then less than $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ by standard fact about alternating series.